# Collect all ID's MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've done this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT image, id FROM store WHERE username = '$username_show'");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        $ids = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $ids = $ids['id'];

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {    
        echo "<img src='get.php?id=$ids[$i]' height='300'><p/>";        
   }
```

I want to show all of my photos that has that username. But the $ids array only gets one index, and that's the last ID. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mysql_* functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Well.. That wont help me i guess? I will take a look at that though, ty.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Matthew said thet are deprecated use :

```
// mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT image, id FROM store WHERE username = '$username_show'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo htmlentities($row['row']);

// PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->query("SELECT image, id FROM store WHERE username = '$username_show'");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['row']);
```

---

**To answer your comment :**
*- use the array function*

```
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
```

---

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT  id FROM store WHERE username = '$username_show'");
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try to learn this instead then. But how do I solve my problem? I want to have an array, with all the collted ID's.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really get it.. Will all my ID's be stored in this $result_array?

Comment: I'm very new to mysql and php, thats why :)

Comment: here is a link for basics array lessons - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Comment: and this a complete article - http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlfetcharray.php

Comment: I updated the answer by changing `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc` when using `mysqli`; that was a typo.